# How to change the pixel width and height of an image from a file object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, upload

I have an input where the client can upload a file. I have already implemented a validation that the file is an image or a gif. I need an option where the image needs to be scaled down to 30px width and height(no cropping, just scaling down) before it is uploaded to the backend. The image is uploaded as a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to use an image manipulation library.

Here is a list of the most common used.
Implementing it all on your own would be very tedious.
[image manipulation libraries](https://blog.bitsrc.io/image-manipulation-libraries-for-javascript-187fde1ad5af)

alternatively, pasting the image into a canvas, scale it (the way you want) and then extracting it would also be possible.

But imho I think the best way is a library that is well supported

Comment: Thanks, I used pica